# How do I print a char pointer returned by a function (C)?

Tags: c, string.h

I am trying to print a char pointer returned by a function but the output is always gibberish.

I have tried changing the function type to char [] but this gives error.
 I have also tried casting the char [] to char * but this causes stack corruption. I noticed that if variable 'b' is printed within the function before the return statement, it displays correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *the()
{
    char a[100] = "Ace of Spades";
    char * b = &a[0];

    return b;
}
int main(void)
{

        printf("%s\n", the());

}
```

Expected Result:[image]
Actual Result:[image]

Comment: you access to a local variable whose does not exist anymore, the behavior is undefined, copy / duplicate the string before to return it or move _a_ static

Comment: `char*` and `char[]` are the same thing

Comment: @bruno I don't understand your correction, copy the string to where?

Comment: @gogaz You can't declare a function as char [] (), I've tried it with VS 2013

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate question.  The `char a[100]` ceases to exist when the function containing it returns.

Comment: @gogaz not exactly but `char[]` decays to a pointer here.

Comment: @jacobay43 you can duplicate it (strdup), do not forget to free it later in _main_ in that case

Comment: @bruno When I duplicate it, how can the duplicate be returned?

Comment: @jacobay43 replace `return b;` by  `return strdup(b);` then in _main_ replace `printf("%s\n", the());` by `char * s = the(); puts(s); free(s);` (_puts_ more practical than _printf_ in your case)

Comment: @bruno, it works now, thanks